# Where System.out writes in a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, system.out

I am just curious to know, what happens when System.out.print() is called in a servlet?

Where does it write the text?

Or is there any significant use of System.out in a servlet?

Comment: http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2ee/servlets/servletoutput.html

Comment: Displays output in the server console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on your servlet container.

For [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Console) :

> When running Tomcat on unixes, the console output is usually
>   redirected to the file named catalina.out. The name is configurable
>   using an environment variable. (See the startup scripts). Whatever is
>   written to System.err/out will be caught into that file.

For [jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/StdErrStdOut), you can redirect standard output to a file :

> It is possible to redirect all output sent to stderr and stdout to a
>   file that can be rolled over [...]

Answer (score 5):

System.out.print()  writes on `Server Console`.

Comment: Server>> Apache Tomcat >> Right click >> View Server Output

Comment: @IronBlossom which is where on IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

It will write in the console .System.out is generally used in servlet to verify some piece of code is working,which we can refer in console.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is any significant use of System.out in a `servlet`. Beacause , Servlet is a web technology for generating dynamic web pages. Normally , it returns response to `HTML`  page. So, there is no need for print data on `Console`.

For Console print, there are many other options except `Servlet`. But still if we want to print data on console then you can write inside `service(),doGet(),doPost()` and other methods also :-

```
System.out.println("YOUR MESSAGE");
```

But, it is recommended to avoid that.